# Setting the type of variable from an object property

Tags: typescript

I am trying to set the type of a variable to a property of an object, such as in the code below.

```js
class Foo {

}

const obj = {
  Foo,
};

const foo: Foo; // valid
const bar: obj.Foo; // Cannot find namespace 'obj'.
```

This gives me the error `Cannot find namespace 'obj'`. Is there a way of setting the type of a variable from an object property, such that `foo` and `bar` are of type `Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the type of the `obj` (using `typeof`), then you can query its `Foo` property type:

```
declare const bar: (typeof obj)["Foo"];
```

Pay attention `bar` is `constructor`, not an instance.

If you're looking for instance type, you can use [`InstanceType`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types) utility:

```
declare const bar: InstanceType<(typeof obj)["Foo"]>;
```

If you need something more reusable:

```
type Obj = typeof obj;
type GetType<K extends keyof Obj> = InstanceType<Obj[K]>

const bar: GetType<'Foo'> = new obj.Foo();
```

Comment: That could also work, but declaring `const bar: obj.Foo` (as I think the user expects it) would be `declare const bar: InstanceType<(typeof obj)["Foo"]>` a bit  of a mouthful ..

Comment: Thanks, just was also adding `InstanceType` part

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to add a type to an object type. The closest thing you can do is use a namespace definition. A namespace can have both variables and types. A namespace is represented as an object at runtime so it might be close enough to what you need:

```
class Foo {

}
type _Foo = Foo;
const _Foo = Foo;
namespace obj {
    export type Foo = _Foo;
    export const Foo = _Foo; // to allow instantiation through obj.Foo
};

const foo: Foo; // valid
const bar: obj.Foo = new obj.Foo()
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way of decreasing the size of this? I'm dealing with 90~ classes

Comment: @SebastiaanYN Problem is you are using the same name, so the external name will be aliased, hence the need for the external `_` definitions. Also you need to export both the type and the value (`const`) to make a class work exactly as before .. not sure how I would reduce it given these constraints ..

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the type it in a compact way like this `let bar: {Foo}`

***Update***

Also since I mentioned `obj` is not a namespace so I tried the `typeof` keyword since we want the `type` of that property. so you can try it out  like this

`let bar: typeof obj.Foo;`

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. That simply says that `bar` is an object with a property `Foo` of type `any`.

Comment: @SebastiaanYN Since `obj` is *NOT* a namespace (i.e a `class` or an `Interface`) It would be impossible to set the *Type* to an object's *Property*. Also because the `obj.value` syntax get's the value of the property not its type

Comment: @SebastiaanYN I have updated the answer. Please check it out now

Comment: `const bar: typeof obj.Foo = new obj.Foo();` would give `Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'typeof Foo'.`

Comment: @SebastiaanYN I am also getting the error in TS but if you run the code and  see the console It does create the `Foo` object and with no error in the browser (Strange)

Comment: That's because the error is coming from TypeScript during compile time. When there is an issue with types only the compiler complains. The compiled JavaScript it will output is however valid.